# Value from Input box not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to create a simple to-do application. The list itself works perfectly fine and things get added how they should.

However, now I am trying to have a sort of timeline that basically shows the todo items in a different style.

Now the issue is every time an item gets added, it shows up in the regular checklist but not in the new timeline. The LI gets created but with no content inside of it.

Any of you guys know how I can display the input value from the input box into the timeline as I did with the regular checklist?

```js
let inputValue = document.getElementById("inputValue");
let addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
let frm = document.querySelector("form");


//Prevent Refresh
function handleForm(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
}

function addItem() {

    // Check Input for empty value
    if (inputValue.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Your Input was empty");
        return;
    }
    
    //Create LI and append to UL
    let listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = inputValue.value;
    let ul = document.getElementById("list-ul")
    ul.appendChild(listItem);
    listItem.className = "list-item";

    //Create Delet button and append to LI
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    deleteButton.className = "delete-button";
    deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>';
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);

    //Reset the Input
    frm.reset();
    //Prevent refresh
    frm.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);

    //Delete Function
    function deleteItem(e) {
        console.log("Item deleted");
        listItem.remove();
    }

    //Timeline
    let timeline = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline");
    let timeUl = document.getElementById("time-ul");
    //Create LI for timeline
    let timelineItem = document.createElement("li");
    timelineItem.innerText = inputValue.value;
    timeUl.appendChild(timelineItem);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e7a951e13e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <main>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>To Do</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputValue">
            <button type="button" id="addButton" onclick="addItem();">Add Item</button>
<!--             <button type="button" id="clearAll" onclick="clearAll();">Clear All</button> -->
        </form>
        <div id="list-container">
            <ul id="list-ul">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline">
            <ul id="time-ul">
                
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</main>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: its because you reset the form prior to using the form input value.  @ // Reset the Input

Comment: @RandyCasburn lmao thank you. Such a stupid mistake...

Comment: @AdrianB., Thats because of restting of the form before adding to timeline.. Consider restetting to the bottom of add item function. Fixed solution: https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/QWEyWOm

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I appreciate it. Randy already told me... What an easy and stupid mistake hahaha. Appreciate the help tho! :D

Comment: @AdrianB. No issues, Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reseting the form and later trying to access the value from the input, which was cleared.

Move `frm.reset();` to after the Timeline is updated.

```
...

//Timeline
let timeline = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline");
let timeUl = document.getElementById("time-ul");
//Create LI for timeline
let timelineItem = document.createElement("li");
timelineItem.innerText = inputValue.value;
timeUl.appendChild(timelineItem);

//Reset the Input
frm.reset();
```

Another option you have is to store the input value in a variable and use it in your calls before resetting the form.

```
const todoValue = inputValue.value;

...

//Timeline
timelineItem.innerText = todoValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i was just blind and forgot that i cleared the input by resetting the form.